# My google apps script to send email after a form submission is not handling an array formula in the underlying spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have searched for an answer without any luck so I'm hoping someone smarter than me will have seen this before.  Here's my issue:

I.  I have a Google form tied to a spreadsheet to capture order data. That spreadsheet has an arrayformula in one cell to calculate a dollar amount based on selections made in the form (SubTotal).

II. I created a GAS to send a confirmation email based on the form's data to the ordering party and copy other interested parties.  It has a trigger event for OnFormSubmit.

III. Everything works great, except the value of the field SubTotal shows up as "Undefined" in the email generated by the script.

Here's the GAS code:

```
function orderconfemail(e) {
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var playerLastName = e.values[1];
  var playerFirstName = e.values[2];
  var jerseyNumber = e.values[3];
  var ageGroup = e.values[5];
  var parentLastName = e.values[6];
  var parentFirstName = e.values[7];
  var toAddress = e.values[8];
  var ccAddress = e.values[17];
  var teamName = e.values[13];
  var coachName = e.values[14];
  var mgrName = e.values[16];
  var homeSize = e.values[20];
  var homeQty = e.values[21];
  var awayOrdered = e.values[22];
  var awaySize = e.values[23];
  var awayQty = e.values[24];
  var shortSize = e.values[26];
  var shortQty = e.values[27];
  var jcktOrdered = e.values[28];
  var jcktSize = e.values[29];
  var jcktQty = e.values[30];
  var pntsOrdered = e.values[31];
  var pntsSize = e.values[32];
  var pntsQty = e.values[33];
  var bagOrdered = e.values[34];
  var bagQty = e.values[35];
  var orderTotal = e.values[36];
  var subject = "Futura FC Uniform Order Confirmation for " + playerFirstName + " " + playerLastName;
  var htmlBody = "Thank you for your uniform order, " + parentFirstName + "! Your order date / time was: " + timestamp + "." + 
      "<br/>&nbsp;</br>Your order details are as follows: " +
      "<br/>&nbsp;<br/><b>Player Name:</b> " + playerFirstName + " " + playerLastName +
      "<br/><b>Jersey Number:</b> " + jerseyNumber +
      "<br/><b>Age Goup:</b> " + ageGroup +
      "<br/><b>Team:</b> " + teamName +
      "<br/><b>Coach:</b> " + coachName +
      "<br/><b>Manager:</b> " + mgrName +
      "<br/><b>Home Jersey Size:</b> " + homeSize + 
      "<br/><b>Home Jersey Qty:</b> " + homeQty +
      "<br/><b>Away Jersey Ordered?</b> " + awayOrdered +
      "<br/><b>Away Jersey Size:</b> " + awaySize +
      "<br/><b>Away Jersey Qty:</b> " + awayQty +
      "<br/><b>Short Size:</b> " + shortSize +
      "<br/><b>Short Qty:</b> " + shortQty +
      "<br/><b>Warm Up Jacket Ordered?</b> " + jcktOrdered +
      "<br/><b>Jacket Size:</b> " + jcktSize +
      "<br/><b>Jacket Qty:</b> " + jcktQty +
      "<br/><b>Warm Up Pants Ordered?</b> " + pntsOrdered +
      "<br/><b>Pants Size:</b> " + pntsSize +
      "<br/><b>Pants Qty:</b> " + pntsQty +
      "<br/><b>Backpack Ordered?</b> " + bagOrdered +
      "<br/><b>Backpack Qty:</b> " + bagQty +
      "<br/>&nbsp;<br/><b>Your Order Total:</b> " + orderTotal;
  var optAdvancedArgs = {cc: ccAddress, bcc: "someone@aol.com,someone@embarqmail.com", htmlBody: htmlBody};
  MailApp.sendEmail(toAddress, subject, "Message Body", optAdvancedArgs);
}
```

And here's how it shows up in my email (I cut out everything but the subtotal line for space's sake).

> Thank you for your uniform order, Parent! Your order date / time was:
>   5/23/2012 20:10:23.
>
> **Your Order Total: undefined**

The spreadsheet does show the correct, calculated SubTotal but the email does not. Can I:

I.  Calculate that subtotal in the GAS?

II. Force the script to write the row to the spreadsheet before it sends the email?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Henrique. Your best bet is to calculate the total inside your GAS script.
Instead of

var orderTotal = e.values[36];

you can have

var orderTotal = // Make your calculation here .
However, ensure that you have parseInt(e.values[x]) since all parameters in e.values are strings.

Comment: Thanks! I'll see if I can figure out that calculation in the GAS now.  :D

Answer (score 0):

> II. Force the script to write the row to the spreadsheet before it
>   sends the email?

The data is already on the spreadsheet before the function is triggered (therefore, there's no way to force it).

The problem is that you're getting the values passed in the event parameter, which are what were sent in the form (all strings), and not the values on the spreadsheet, as you thought.

Unfortunately, identifying the row where the actual form values were salved (so you can get them) is not as easy as we'd want. Please take a look at [issue 128](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=128) for more.

Anyway, in your scenario I think it's much, much easier to just calculate the `orderTotal` in the script itself.

Answer (score 0):

Both Henrique and Srik were very helpful in pointing me in the right direction.  I was able to create another variable that parsed each qty to an integer and then do some simple math to make the calculations. Here's what my properly functioning GAS script looks like now:

```
function orderconfemail(e) {
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var playerLastName = e.values[1];
  var playerFirstName = e.values[2];
  var jerseyNumber = e.values[3];
  var ageGroup = e.values[5];
  var parentLastName = e.values[6];
  var parentFirstName = e.values[7];
  var toAddress = e.values[8];
  var ccAddress = e.values[17];
  var teamName = e.values[13];
  var coachName = e.values[14];
  var mgrName = e.values[16];
  var homeSize = e.values[20];
  var homeQty = e.values[21];
  var homeQtyInt = parseInt(e.values[21]);
  var awayOrdered = e.values[22];
  var awaySize = e.values[23];
  var awayQty = e.values[24];
  var awayQtyInt = parseInt(e.values[24]);
  var shortSize = e.values[26];
  var shortQty = e.values[27];
  var shortQtyInt = parseInt(e.values[27]);
  var jcktOrdered = e.values[28];
  var jcktSize = e.values[29];
  var jcktQty = e.values[30];
  var jcktQtyInt = parseInt(e.values[30]);
  var pntsOrdered = e.values[31];
  var pntsSize = e.values[32];
  var pntsQty = e.values[33];
  var pntsQtyInt = parseInt(e.values[33]);
  var bagOrdered = e.values[34];
  var bagQty = e.values[35];
  var bagQtyInt = parseInt(e.values[35]);
  var orderTotal = ((homeQtyInt*40.50)+(awayQtyInt*25)+(shortQtyInt*24)+(jcktQtyInt*50)+(pntsQtyInt*32.50)+(bagQtyInt*40));
  var subject = "TEST! Futura FC Uniform Order Confirmation for " + playerFirstName + " " + playerLastName;
  var htmlBody = "Thank you for your uniform order, " + parentFirstName + "! Your order date / time was: " + timestamp + "." + 
      "<br/>&nbsp;</br>Your order details are as follows: " +
      "<br/>&nbsp;<br/><b>Player Name:</b> " + playerFirstName + " " + playerLastName +
      "<br/><b>Jersey Number:</b> " + jerseyNumber +
      "<br/><b>Age Goup:</b> " + ageGroup +
      "<br/><b>Team:</b> " + teamName +
      "<br/><b>Coach:</b> " + coachName +
      "<br/><b>Manager:</b> " + mgrName +
      "<br/><b>Home Jersey Size:</b> " + homeSize + 
      "<br/><b>Home Jersey Qty:</b> " + homeQty +
      "<br/><b>Away Jersey Ordered?</b> " + awayOrdered +
      "<br/><b>Away Jersey Size:</b> " + awaySize +
      "<br/><b>Away Jersey Qty:</b> " + awayQty +
      "<br/><b>Short Size:</b> " + shortSize +
      "<br/><b>Short Qty:</b> " + shortQty +
      "<br/><b>Warm Up Jacket Ordered?</b> " + jcktOrdered +
      "<br/><b>Jacket Size:</b> " + jcktSize +
      "<br/><b>Jacket Qty:</b> " + jcktQty +
      "<br/><b>Warm Up Pants Ordered?</b> " + pntsOrdered +
      "<br/><b>Pants Size:</b> " + pntsSize +
      "<br/><b>Pants Qty:</b> " + pntsQty +
      "<br/><b>Backpack Ordered?</b> " + bagOrdered +
      "<br/><b>Backpack Qty:</b> " + bagQty +
      "<br/>&nbsp;<br/><b>Your Order Total:</b> " + orderTotal;
  var optAdvancedArgs = {cc: ccAddress, bcc: "mmcgriggs@aol.com,futurauniforms@embarqmail.com", htmlBody: htmlBody};
  MailApp.sendEmail(toAddress, subject, "Message Body", optAdvancedArgs);
}
```

One other "gotcha" I encountered as well.  My form had a few of the Qty fields that allowed a NULL value.  When that value was encountered, the OrderTotal would be reported in the email as "NaN".  I simply went back and made 0 the default for all my quantity fields to correct this. Thanks everyone!